# Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider' not found on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I recently tried installing jenssegers/agent in Laravel by following the instructions on this GitHub page: https://github.com/jenssegers/agent. However, I ran into an error where I received the message "Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider' not found" on my browser.

Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have.

Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi2rN.png)

I've already added Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider::class under 'providers' and 'Agent' => Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent::class in 'aliases' in the config/app.php file and ran composer install.

Comment: Have you tried `composer dumpautoload`? Also it looks like a package that hasn't received any releases in nearly 3 years and no development at all for more than 2 years. It might be abandoned

Comment: it responds with something similar:


'In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1'

Comment: Are you sure the package is properly installed? Check the following files exist: `vendor/jenssegers/agent/src/Agent.php` `vendor/jenssegers/agent/src/AgentServiceProvider.php`

Comment: Yes, they are installed in the folders you say.

Comment: Ok the problem was that i was running 'composer install' outside of my project folder, now it works propertly. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was running "composer install" outside of my project folder.
Now it works properly. Thanks!